# d3.js histogram not working with array of total frequency for each bins

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following this link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450 . Now the major difference is instead of having all the data for each bins , I got total number of data for each bins.

Here is my working copy of jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1u53ed4p/

I am not able to create `d3 histogram bins` based on my data.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: As per my understanding I think `histogram bins` concept is not applicable here. It is only applicable for segmentation of data into ranges ?

Comment: The problem comes from your misunderstanding of how are the `data` for creating an histogram. Right now, your data has all the bins and the frequencies! You can create an bar chart with it, but not an histogram. To create an histogram, your data should be like this: `[0.32, 0.44, 0.12, 0.65, 0.98, 0.23, 0.87]`. Then, the histogram layout would separate it in bins (from 0.00 to 0.2, from 0.2 to 0.4 etc) and compute the frequencies.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado correct agree. That is why I have mentioned `histogram bins` concept is not applicable here. But if I got bins and total numbers I cant draw histogram out of it , that's little wired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix https://jsfiddle.net/9wq74rok/ .

Eliminated

```
var bins = d3.histogram()
   .domain(x.domain())
   .thresholds(x.ticks(10))
   (data);
```

Used

```
d.frequency
```

In place of

```
d.length
```

Any modification/enhancement on top of this welcome . Would like to add a nice tooltip.